# Shading Area Between Two Line Charts and Axes

Tags: excel, charts, fill, area

I am on day #2 of searching the web and, while I have found plenty of hits that seem like they should work, none of them seem to apply to my particular situation.

I have an Excel chart with two series displayed.  One is a sort of exponential decay curve, and one is a constant that intersects with the exponential curve, but does not continue past it (the final x-value of the orange line is estimated to make it look like it intersects the blue curve):

[image]

The raw data for the blue curve is as follows (leaving off data labels for confidentiality reasons, but x-values are on the left and y-values are on the right):

[image]

The orange line is simply set at 24 all the way across until it intersects with the blue curve.

So here's the problem I need to solve: I need to fill in all of the area below the blue curve with one color, and I need to fill in the area below the orange line with another color. Everything above the blue curve needs to be blank (transparent). Here's an illustration of what I want:

[image]

I know in order to get the coloring/shading I need to use an area chart. However, when I try to change the chart type to Area the scales of the axes change for each series and they no longer match up, and I am unable to edit the axes (can't set min, max, etc) to make them match up again. Additionally, only the area directly beneath the constant line fills in (as expected), but I am looking for a way to fill in the area between the orange line, the blue curve, and the axes:

[image]

How might one go about doing what I need to do?

If there's any other information I could provide that would be of help, please let me know and I'll be sure to add it in.

EDIT: 
I can extend the orange line to follow the blue line off to the right, which may help fill in the lower area. However, when I switch to an area chart I still get the issue with mismatched axes with scale I can't edit:

[image]

Notice how the "567" point (the x-value where the orange line should intersect the blue curve) is spaced evenly between "500" and "600", rather than scaling slightly to the right of center as I would have expected.

**How do I keep the spacing of one tick every 100 units on the x-axis but keep the datapoint for 567?**

Comment: Well excel did exactly what you asked it to do, colour the area beneath the curve....

Comment: @Luuklag Understood, and I don't fault Excel for it at all. I'm simply looking for a way to have Excel do what I need using existing tools.

Comment: I would just have two charts : one does the blue and the other the orange then lay the orange chart on top of the blue and make it transparent ... worked a treat in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the **intersection point's coordinates** (graphically or analitically), then **split your data in two separate series** within the same graph as follows :

[image]

---

**Edit post comment section :**

---

For some reason  x-values are considered by default as text.

**Righ click** the `x-axis` > `format` > **Select** `date on the axis`

Then play with the `principal` and `base` in `days`/`months` to have the intervals you want.

Good parameters for this data :

- `main` : 100 in days
- `base` : in days

[image]

Comment: This seems promising, though the resolution of the exponential curve is much lower, and if I try to add a datapoint between two standard x-axis ticks it ruins the scale of the x-axis

Comment: Even with discrete data you may be able to localy increase the resolution through an interpolation or regression of some kind.
1) could you post your data ?
2) is this only for display are you allowed to alterate the data to make it look better (smoother) ?

Comment: I have added the raw data to my question

Comment: I split the data into two halves, split at the "567" point on the x-axis. I'm still having a problem with "567" being spaced evenly between "500" and "600", throwing off the scale of the x-axis. In other words, I have an x-axis with "400", "500", "567", "600", and "700" (and other values) all spaced evenly

Comment: Any thoughts on how to prevent Excel from spacing the x-axis ticks evenly when one of them is not on the same scale as the rest?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Yep, that's about where I'm at right now. However, if you look at the orange part of the chart in your second image, you'll see it droops down between 500 and 600. I need it to go straight across until it intercepts with the blue curve, and then I need it to follow the blue curve. It looks like you're right where I am now.

Comment: Solution 2 should fit you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that completely changes the values on the x-axis

Comment: Put everything in days with main unit = 100. Then you have 200-1200 with the 100 interval. -- Final update for clarity

Comment: Ok, took some finagling but finally got it to work! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would just have two identical charts : one does the blue and the other the orange then lay the orange chart on top of the blue and make it transparent ... worked a treat in the past...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do but when I change the charts to area charts (in order to fill them in) the axis scales change and it doesn't work the way I would expect. See the edit to my original post.

Comment: Are you starting with identical charts? If the x-axis data is not the same then it mis-matches - I had to play with the y-axis values to get the common part to behave identically...

Comment: The X-axis values are not the same, and here lies the problem. I already know that this is the issue, but I cannot see a practical alternative at this point. The datapoints for the blue curve are spaced every 100 ticks (meters, in this chart), but  in order to make the orange line meet up with the blue curve I need a resolution capable of supporting an x-axis datapoint at 567 meters. This is why they are on two different sets of x-values